# the summation goes to the integration

Tags: integration, limits, irrational-numbers

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ with period $1$. Show that for any irrational number $x$, $\frac { \sum_{k =1 }^ N f (k x ) } { N} \to \int _ 0 ^1 f(t) \, d t $ as $N \to \infty$.

I know that $[kx]$ will be dense in $[0,1]$. But for this problem this seems to be not enough. I feel that I need to know something about how $[kx]$ spreads "evenly" throughout $[0,1]$ as $k$ grows in order to derive the limit. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you need is that $\{kx\}$ is [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) in $[0,1]$.

Comment: consider $N$ such that $|\{ N x \}| < \epsilon$ ? and $f$ is uniformely continuous so that $|f(a + N x) - f(a)| < C \epsilon$